# How to Publish Checked-In changes only in Team Foundation Server 2013 to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssdt, visual-studio-2013

I would like to ask you how to publish checked-in changes only in Team Foundation Server 2013 to SQL Server? It's a new installation of TFS 2013 - installed by me.

Currently when I create new object like table as a part of the project and don't do check-in on this table and next publish the project, such table is published anyway. I was thinking that only checked-in (approved) changes are published to SQL Server (without objects which has no approval).

It's important because I want publish only complete objects to the SQL Server. Without objects which are still in development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to publish only checked in changes while you have uncommitted development, don't use your development workspace for publishing.  Instead, create a separate workspace for that purpose.  Perform a get latest in the publishing workspace so that it includes only the latest checked in objects and then publish from there.  A separate build box is often used for this purpose in larger development environments.

**EDIT:**

A new workspace for publishing can be created using TFS Source Control Explorer. Select "Workspaces..." from the Workspace drop down and click add.  In the working folder mapping dialog, provide a mnemonic workspace name, specify the same source control folder you use for development but specify a new empty local folder.  Click yes when prompted to get the latest from source control.  This new workspace will contain only the latest checked-in objects.

These development and publishing workspaces share the same source control path but are independent due to the different local folders and files.  Be mindful to make changes only in the development workspace (and get latest to see other team members checked-in changes) and use only get latest to update the deployment workspace.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about such solution. But the question is where I can configure the second (Publishing) workspace to get only the Checked-In changes from first (Development) workspace ? Should I create some connection or link between those two workspaces to let them know that Publishing workspace should get the data from Dev workspace ?

Comment: .@TomaszWieczorkowski, I added more info to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan for detailed explanation! I'll test it and let you know is everything works.